# Access console of new VM without requiring RDP access through firewall?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I don't have outbound RDP access, and want to connect to a new VM created on google cloud.

Is there a built in console for controlling them?

Comment: Or can you change the default RDP port?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the VM serial console.

To access the VM serial console, you have to go to: https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances?project=[your-project-id] then click on the name of your virtual instance, then check the option "Enable connecting to serial ports". After that click on "Connect to serial port"